# Write Regex Compatible with java

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am unable to solve one scenario:
Below is the sample data:

5 AP 7122784

6 APB +5115400852

7 APE ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM

8 APE LAX*ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM

9 APE ERT-EDF@UK.TR.EDS

APE is the identifier which tells us it is a email id field.

We have to pick email id on the basis of below rules:

1. If LAX* is there then get value after LAX* and fetch it. i.e. ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM
2. If email id with LAX* is not in the data(8 APE LAX*ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM -record not there) then then pick all the email ids i.e. ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM and ERT-EDF@UK.TR.EDS.

Could someone please help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to do more than just a Regex expression. This requires an `if`, `else if` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking create a Java code like below:

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String to be scanned to find the pattern.

```
 String regex = "(APE\\sPAX\\*|APE\\s)(?<email>.*)\\s*";

 String string = "5 AP 7122784\n"

 + "6 APB +5115400852\n"

 + "7 APE ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM\n"

 + "8 APE PAX*ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM\n"

 + "9 APE ERT-EDF@UK.TR.EDS";

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {

System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {

 System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));

}
```

}

}

}`

and capture groups with if else inside Java.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLjuP.png)

Scrreenshot of above Java Code:

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
^\d+ +APE +LAX\*(.*)
```

with a multiline flag (`/m` or `(?m)` at the beginning of the regex) to determine if there is a line that begins with one or more digits followed by  more or more spaces followed by `APE` followed by one or more spaces followed by `LAX*`. If there is a match capture group 1 will contain the rest of the line, which is assumed to be an email address. Here that is

```
ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eH4av/2/)

If there is no match use the following regex with a multiline flag:

```
^\d+ +APE +(.*)
```

The contents of capture group 1 for each match is one of the email addresses of interest. Here (after removing the line `8 APE LAX*ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM`) there would be two matches, with the capture group containing `ABC.XYZ@LOM.COM` and `ERT-EDF@UK.TR.EDS`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MYhdBb/1/)